# how to count number of days between two dates and display the result in a textbox in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<li>Date From *<br />
  <input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" value="<?=gf_dateformat($date_from,'Y-m-d') ?>" onclick="javascript: displayDatePicker('date_from', false, 'dmy', '-');" style="width:100px;" />
</li>
<li>Date TO *<br />
  <input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to" value="<?=gf_dateformat($date_to,'Y-m-d') ?>" onclick="javascript: displayDatePicker('date_to', false, 'dmy', '-');" style="width:100px;" onblur="" /> 
</li>                   
<li>No of Days <br />
  <input type="text" name="num_days" id="num_days" required="yes" validate='text'  title="Enter Number of Days"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can find difference of two dates in JS.

```
 var Days = Math.floor((Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

in php you can use this code...

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("2011/07/01");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("2011/07/17");

$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

// and you might want to convert to integer
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to calculate the difference between dates in PHP i.e Procedural and Object Oriented.

### Procedural Style

```
    $datetime1 = date_create('YYYY-mm-dd');
    $datetime2 = date_create('YYYY-mm-dd');
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

```
    Object Oriented Style
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('YYYY-mm-dd');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('YYYY-mm-dd');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

You can use either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below. Works excellent:

```
/**
 * Calculates the difference between two dates in days, months and years.
 * @param $start_date string Starting date.
 * @param $end_date string Ending date.
 * @return string Specifying the days, months and years in difference.
 * @category Date
 */
function get_date_diff($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $diff = abs(strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date));

    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    return "{$days} days, {$months} months, {$years} years";
}
```